# What Block Producer resources are available?

Tags: block-producer, documentation

Running a Block Producer is a complex job. BP candidates would find useful  tools, tips, documentation, security tips, setup examples, cost calculators.
What of these and other BP resources are available?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: EOS New York is trying to create and maintain an open-source resource for this [here](https://www.eosdocs.io/bp/).

---

Nothing too organised as far as I know, but there are bits of information spread around:

- [Best practices and fundamentally sound principals in Information Security and Privacy](https://forums.eosgo.io/discussion/1504/bp-infrastructure-best-practices-and-fundamentally-sound-principals-in-information-security) from EOSSweden
  [image: Sweden BP Security chart]
- [How to Achieve a Perfect Score on BP Reports](https://forums.eosgo.io/discussion/856/bp-candidates-how-to-achieve-a-perfect-score-on-bp-reports-9-and-10-releasing-may-16-30) from EOS Go
- Candidacy announcement posts from other BPs (e.g. [EOS Liquid announcement](https://steemit.com/bancor/@bancor-network/announcing-bancor-as-an-eos-block-producer-candidate)) or current tech stach (e.g. [EOS New York Tech](https://www.eosnewyork.io/tech))
  [image: EOS Liquid architecture]
- [EOS Resource Planner](https://www.eosrp.io/) to an extent, but more relevant to dapp developers.
- [Another guide](https://steemit.com/eos-blockproducers/@xebb/eos-block-producer-candidacy) from EOS Sweden where they attempt to brek down the necessary architecture for running a BP

Please note that I'm not affiliated in any way with any of the BPs mentioned, nor do I recommend any of them over the others. I suggest you check out https://bp.eosgo.io/ for other BPs and their blogs/announcements for tips, as I don't believe there's any aggregator for these resources yet.